Implementing Classification with Multi-Tenancy
Is it currently possible to utilize the classification endpoint alongside multi-tenancy in the latest version? I couldn't find any documentation regarding this feature. it's not implemented yet in v4.
As a workaround, I understand that using v3 is necessary. However, even with v3, there doesn't appear to be a straightforward way to execute classification while specifying a particular tenant for the classification task.
When attempting to run classification without specifying a tenant, I encounter the error message:
'error': 'classification failed: retrieve to-be-classifieds: object search at index trajectory: class Trajectory has multi-tenancy enabled, but request was without tenant'

Is there a known solution or workaround for this issue, or am I missing something?

Duda from Weaviate here.
Right now, the classification feature is not implemented for a multi tenant collection.
Please, feel free to open a feature request in our Github repository here:
https://github.com/weaviate/weaviate/issues
Thanks!
